# JavaScript - Dropdown does not work

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to achieve one simple requirement, but couldn't make it!

My requirement is very simple - wanna display some alert to the user based on the options he selects from the drop down.

Below is the code, I've designed now. Please check and correct me where I'm going wrong.

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
    var txt = this.getField("ddPortfolio").value;
    If(txt == "Distribution")
    window.alert("distribution");
</SCRIPT>

<div style="float:right">
<select name = "ddPortfolio">
   <option value="volvo">-- Select Option --</option>
   <option value="saab">Training</option>
   <option value="mercedes">Internal</option>
   <option value="audi">External</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: is this code is right?

Comment: Javascript is case-sensitive -- that's `if`, not `If`.

Answer (score 2):

You have some syntax errors. Also there is no `Distribution` value in your options. I think you want this:

**html**

```
<div style="float:right">
    <select name = "ddPortfolio" onchange="test(this);">
       <option value="volvo">-- Select Option --</option>
       <option value="saab">Training</option>
       <option value="mercedes">Internal</option>
       <option value="audi">External</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**js**

```
function test(obj){
    var txt = obj.value;
    if(txt == "audi"){
        window.alert("audi");
    }
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x4bTK/9/)

Answer (score 0):

You checked `If(txt == "Distribution")` but that was not one of the options in your select in the code you provided. also it's the `onchange` triegger you need

You also need to add an id to the select so you can reference it for example

HTML snippet

```
<select name = "ddPortfolio" id = "ddPortfolio">
```

Javscript

```
   var MyColumn = document.getElementById("ddPortfolio");
   MyColumn.onchange = function(){if (MyColumn.value == "audi") {alert('hi');}};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/64Z7H/

Comment: you forgot to draw the OP's attention to the fact that they'd have to `id` the select tag in order your code to work... plus if you have additional comments to make to your answer, edit your answer instead of commenting... (by the way, the downvote is *not* from me)

Comment: @webeno I have taken into account your feedback and edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
 <select onchange="getval(this);">
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
 </select>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getval(sel) {
      alert(sel.value)        ;
}
</script>
```

Simple Drop down box working using javascript.